# One word for "The original person who experienced an event"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The person whom the story belongs to is not telling the story, but someone else is telling it on his behalf. In that case, what's one concise word or phrase to replaced the bold part above?

> This story is recounted by another person on behalf of **the original person that experienced this story.**

This phrase is added before the actual story is recounted, so this is pretty much a reminder to the audience that the person they see telling the story is not the real guy. The best I can get to is "This story is recounted by someone else on behalf of the true protagonist," but that still sounds off.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127696/discussion-on-question-by-nicholas-one-word-for-the-original-person-who-experie).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are talking about a **narrator** in your question, but an **eyewitness** in your title.

> **narrator**
>
> *noun*
>
> a person who narrates something, especially a character who recounts the events of a novel or narrative poem.
>
> (From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/narrator))

> **narrate**
>
> *verb*
>
> give a spoken or written account of.
>
> *verb:* **narrate**; *3rd person present:* **narrates**; *past tense:* **narrated**; *past participle:* **narrated**; *gerund or present participle:* **narrating**
>
> (From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/narrate))

Comment: Eyewitness is someone who's seen it. I'm looking for a word for someone who's experienced it. For example, an eyewitness in a car accident is not the one involved in the accident, i.e. the main character of the accident.

Comment: The main character of an accident is called a "victim". However, I don't think an English word exists to describe "someone who experiences something". In order to use a general term to describe someone experiencing something, we need to know the experience. A child who goes to school is called a student. Student is the term used for someone who experiences school as a child.

Comment: Why not just say, "This story is recounted by [NARRATOR'S NAME] on behalf of [PERSON'S NAME]."?

Answer (score 1):

A **participant** is someone who's involved in an event, who [participates](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/participates) or takes part. ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/participant)) Lexico has [many examples](https://www.lexico.com/definition/participant), including people taking part in politics, active members of organisations, people attending conferences or other events, and subjects in scientific studies.

If the person is not actively involved they might be a **spectator** "one who looks on or watches" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spectator)). [Merriam-Webster also has](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experient) **experient**: "a person undergoing an experience or having experience": this is more passive than participant but it wouldn't be limited to those who watch: it could include more direct experience.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that participant can convey the meaning "the main character" on its own. Even a side character is a participant.

Comment: No, a participant is not merely an observer or a spectator.

Comment: If a story is being told, then, among the participants, there is the **protagonist**

Answer (score -1):

There is this

> **eyewitness** NOUN
> A person who has personally seen something happen and so can give a first-hand description of it.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/eyewitness)

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - Yes. ***secondhand***.  The story is being told secondhand.

Comment: HAL pointed out the problem.  "Eyewitness" answers the question in the title, not the one in the text of the question.